# How to remove Google FinderHelper - its taking loads of my CPU

Tags: finder, google, google-apps

When I click on my battery I constantly see this Google icon (FinderHelper) in there, is there any way to reduce its CP usage?

[image]

Comment: I doubt it, other than uninstalling Google Drive. Having said that, & I don't use laptops so this has never been a concern for me - but have you investigated what is considered 'significant', or even if there always has to be 4 things listed in there, no matter how much they're using, something always has to be 'worst'...

Comment: its just there all the time, but not taking much in the activity monitor

Comment: The "significant energy" list only includes items that are actually using a meaningful amount of battery. If no apps are doing anything unusual, the list will be empty.

Comment: update, i nuked this crap off my mac

Comment: You can post an answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted this app from my Mac, which solved my problem.